# Google READ_CALL_LOG permission policy changes

Tags: android, google-play

Our Apps reads the incoming phone number and displays it in our app and disconnects the call after that. We can't remove READ_CALL_LOG permission as this is the most important feature of our app. We submitted "Google Play Permissions Declaration Form" after making our app as default dialer but it got rejected and the reason mentioned is :

```
"The declared feature {Default Dialer} is allowed; however we 
determined it to be unnecessary for the core functionality of your app.
```

What could be other alternative so that our app can use this permission

Comment: Have you got any work around? I am facing same issue.

Comment: No, we didn't got any work around yet. Without this permission, it used to work below Pie version, but in Pie this permission is mandatory now